# Question on the Rotating Wave Approximation (RWA) for quadratic coupling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-optics, approximations

I have a very specific question.

I was solving a problem and I have a particular query related to it.

Consider

\begin{align}
F
&=\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}(\hat{b}^\dagger+\hat{b})^2
\\&=\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}((\hat{b}^\dagger)^2+(\hat{b}^\dagger\hat{b})+(\hat{b}\hat{b}^\dagger)+(\hat{b})^2)
\end{align}

Consider the unitary operator $$U=e^{i\omega_{b} t(\hat{b}^\dagger\hat{b})}$$

Then using the BCH (Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff) formula

$$UFU^\dagger=\hat{a}^\dagger\hat{a}((\hat{b}^\dagger)^2e^{-2i\omega_{b}t}+(\hat{b}^\dagger\hat{b})+(\hat{b}\hat{b}^\dagger)+(\hat{b})^2e^{2i\omega_{b}t})$$

Can the terms $$(\hat{b}^\dagger)^2e^{-2i\omega_{b}t} \quad \text{and} \quad (\hat{b})^2e^{2i\omega_{b}t}$$ be ignored using the rotating wave approximation?

Comment: What are the commutation relations of the operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applicability of the RWA always depends (like all approximations) on the conditions.

That said, those terms do look like they are likely to average out to zero in the same way that the regular RWA works. Ultimately, it depends on how big $\omega_b$ is, but if your base approximations already include ignoring any energy levels that are below $2\omega_b$, then you absolutely should ignore those terms.

(... again, depending on the details.)